# apexcharts different options for axis range

Tags: javascript, charts, apexcharts

Let's take a look at the simple chart data:

it has (x,y) pairs:

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | -3 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 7 |
| 3 | 8 |
| 4 | 15 |
| 5 | 0 |

The idea is to create a basic line chart, using VueJS in my case, but the idea can be generalized to JavaScript.

I have a `series` array of objects, where each object has x and y coordinates:

```
series = [
  {
    x: 0,
    y: -3
  },
  {
    x: 1,
    y: 2
  },
  ...
]
```

This series is part of `options` object:

```
const options = { 
  chart: {
    type: 'line'
  },
  series: series 
}

const chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);

chart.render();
```

And the chart is rendered.
Now, let's say I want to append the data to that chart - add 2 new (x,y) pairs

```
const newData = [
  {
    x: 6,
    y: 20
  },
  {
    x: 7,
    y: -10
  }
]

chart.appendData([{ data: chartData }])
```

I would also like that newly appendedData has, for example, different color, fill, or something else - so newly added data displays differently than old data.

Feel free to point me to documentation if I missed anything, but I searched through apex chart methods, and the only thing that looks remotely close to this would be inside

**updateOptions()** method, the **redrawPath** flag ([updateOptions docs](https://apexcharts.com/docs/methods/#updateOptions):

> When the chart is re-rendered, should it draw from the existing paths
> or completely redraw the chart paths from the beginning. By default,
> the chart is re-rendered from the existing paths

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to style the new data differently, you'll want to put these data points into a different series using the [`appendSeries`](https://apexcharts.com/docs/methods/#appendSeries) method:

```
const newData = [
  {
    x: 6,
    y: 20
  },
  {
    x: 7,
    y: -10
  }
]

chart.appendSeries({
  name: "series-2", // optional
  data: newData
})
```

Most of the styling in ApexCharts is done based on series (more specifically `seriesIndex`). So by placing the new data in a separate series you'll be able to style this second series using an array of, for example, [colors](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/colors/).

You could either specify the color you would like to use as you append the new series of data using the `updateOptions` method you mention, or you can specify it in advance.

```
chartOptions: {
  colors: ["#546E7A", "#E91E63"],
}
```

When working with "[Numeric paired values in XY properties](https://apexcharts.com/docs/series/#numeric-paired-values)", the `xaxis` type also has to be explicitly set to numeric:

```
chartOptions: {
  xaxis: {
    type: 'numeric',
  },
}
```

---

The tricky bit comes when you want to add more data a second time (or third, more time). There are two approaches I can think of here:

1. Shuffle the existing data across to the original series (append `series-2` to `series-1`) - and overwrite `series-2` with your new data. You don't need to edit the `colors` in `chartOptions`.
2. You could shuffle the colors along. If you want all "old" data to have the same color, simply prepend the `colors` array with your base color every time you add a new series. Or if you want each series to have a different color, just append a color every time you add a new series.

Comment: If I add a new separate series, with (x,y) pairs defined in the newData array, it somehow starts from the very beginning, instead of from the _x_ coordinate from the chartData[0] (check [this image](https://ibb.co/ZMRRpd5)).

Comment: Oh yeah, I get the same behaviour when I try it. Adding `xaxis: { type: 'numeric' }` to the `chartOptions` seems to solve it though - [docs reference](https://apexcharts.com/docs/series/).

Comment: Yep, this solves the problem. 
Update your main answer so I can accept it as a solution. Thanks for the effort!